# Magento 2.4 with ElasticSearch - include category name in index?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Is there a way to get Magento 2.4 with ElasticSearch to also index the category name alongside the product? For example, I would like someone searching for "wine" to find not only products with wine in the product name, but also products that are in the "Wine" category.

Is it possible to add additional data into the search index to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found any solution in this?

Comment: No, still looking!

Comment: @fistameeny Did you get any solution for it?

Comment: I didn't. I ended up creating a customer text attribute and populating that with search terms including the primary category name. This only worked for my case as I was importing the data from an external system so could "prepare" that field first.